# Using QWebview gives compiling errors, but not because Qt += webkit is missing from the .pro file

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake, qtwebkit

I made a project in Qt and added a QWebview to it then I added `Qt += webkit` to the `.pro` file. However, upon compiling, I get these to errors:

```
...ui_mainwindow.h:42: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8QWebViewC1EP7QWidget'
...ui_mainwindow.h:45: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8QWebView6setUrlERK4QUrl'
```

The errors refer to here (in `ui_mainwindow.h`):

```
...
    webView = new QWebView(centralWidget); // <-- First error here
    webView->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("webView"));
    webView->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 300, 200));
    webView->setUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("about:blank"))); // <-- Second error here
    MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
...
```

In Program.pro:

```
QT       += core gui webkit
```

I think those errors usually occur without `Qt += webkit`, but in this case that's not what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...ui_mainwindow.h:42: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8QWebViewC1EP7QWidget'

The linker does not find the the webview widget symbol.

> I think those errors usually occur without Qt += webkit, but in this case that's not what's happening.

That is correct, however the QtWebkit module was split into webkit and webkitwidgets in Qt 5 because the widgets were moved usually into their separate module in Qt 5 since the way of building UIs is QtQuick as promoted.

To fix this, you would need to write this in your project file:

```
QT = webkit webkitwidgets
```

Note that it is unnecessary to use the `core` and `gui` modules explicitly since they are added by default. Also, make sure you have the webkitwidgets module installed, too, otherwise even the above will not be enough.

Answer (score 2):

With Qt 5 they introduced some more beyond just webkit:

Try putting in the .pro file: `Qt += core gui webkit widgets webkitwidgets`

Hope that helps.